# Given that $f(1) = f'(1) = 1$, use Taylor polynomials to show that $\lvert f(x) - x \rvert \leq A(x - 1)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Given that $\ f$ has continuous second derivatives in$\ [0,2]$ and  $\ f(1)=f'(1)=1$, I'm trying to prove that for every $\ x \in [0,2]$ exists an A so that: $$
|f(x)-x| \le A(x-1)^2
$$

The second derivative made me try Taylor with little success, so far I manage to develop the data on both sides, but I just can't get them to connect. Any ideas?

Comment: $f(x) - x = f(x) - 1 - 1\cdot (x-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use Taylor expansion. Around $1$, we have that
$$ f(x) = 1 + (x-1) + f''(\xi) \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} = x + f''(\xi)\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$$
where $\xi$ is some number in the between $1$ and $x$. So then
$$ \lvert f(x) - x \rvert = \left \lvert f''(\xi) \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} \right \rvert.$$
Since the second derivative is continuous on a compact interval, it attains a maximum. Call that maximum $M$. Then
$$ \left \lvert \frac{f''(\xi)}{2} \right \rvert \leq \frac{M}{2}$$
and you can choose $A \geq \frac{M}{2}$. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: I'm not sure why you're dividing by $(x-1)^2$ at all. Why are you dividing by $(x - 1)^2$? [p.s. I'm using superpowers to keep these comments clean]

Comment: clean away :). Il'l ask it another way. Isn't your choice for A linked to $\ A(x-1)^2$. How can you know that $\ \frac M2 $ is really smaller than $\ A(x-1)^2$ without removing the parentheses?

Comment: got it, need to split it up to x equals and is different from 1. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: No problem! All good